# `onclick` doesn't work for newly appended items

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

The important part of my code:

```
window.onload = function(){
    function someFunction(){
        [].forEach.call(
            document.querySelectorAll('.button'),
            function(btn){
                btn.onclick = console.log("I BEEN CLICKED!!");
            }
        );  
    }

    someFunction()

};
```

`someFunction`'s `console.log` prints "I BEEN CLICKED" when each `.button` that existed at load time is clicked.

How can I extend this to work for newly-appended `.button` elements that are added later using just plain JavaScript (no jQuery)?

Comment: You can use event delegation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event is not added for future elements, only the ones you have queried so far. You should use event delegation:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.button')) {
    console.log('I have been clicked')
  }
})
```

This will work with future buttons because you are capturing a click on the entire document, but only responding if the event was triggered by clicking a target that matches the `.button` selector.

In some old browsers `matches` is prefixed, but you can [grab a polyfill](https://gist.github.com/elijahmanor/6452535).

Comment: @BhojendraNepal, see if edit helps, also check this tutorial http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: It's important to note that this can cause some surprises in terms of event execution order.

Comment: And by *"some"* old browsers, you mean everything but the latest Chrome and Firefox ?

Comment: @adeneo, on the latest Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, iOS, Android http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector. But not sure if `matches` or `matchesSelector` since the link and the description say different things.

Comment: Yup, it's supported prefixed, as in `webkitMatchesSelector`, the non prefixed version is only supported in the latest Chrome and Firefox (and I think maybe some versions of Safari)

Comment: It's still pretty cool, and makes things a lot easier, it's just not very available yet

Answer (score 1):

when you use querySelectorAll, you are getting a list of current elements with the button class and attatching an event to it. when you add new elements, they don't automatically get the event listener. You have to rerun the function whenever you append or just add the same event to appended items.

Answer (score -1):

As @EvanMosseri said, you can simply call it manually whenever you add a new button. But that's lame, so do this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted',function(){
    someFunction();
}
```

And put all that inside your `window.onload` handler

EDIT: @elclanrs's way is probably better than this, but this way should still work, so I'll leave it here

Comment: That’s really inefficient and will add event listeners multiple times when not setting `on*`.

Comment: @minitech yes, its inefficient but it shouldn't add multiple listeners, since he's using `.onclick`, and setting that erases all previous values of it

Comment: “when not setting `on*`”. The point is that it has a hidden gotcha – lots of `on*`s become `addEventListener` later.